# Appending list inside a for loop

Tags: python, list, append, nltk

I have a two item list, each item is a string of text. I want to loop around both items and basically remove a word if it is NOT in a set of words. However the following code is putting all the words together, instead of created two separate items. I want my updated_list to have two items, one for each original item im updating:

```
#stopwords is a variable for a set of words that I dont want in my final updated list
updated_list = []
articles = list_of_articles

for article in articles:
    for word in article:
         if word not in stopwords:
              updated_list.append(word)


articles = [['this, 'is', 'a', 'test'], ['what', 'is', 'your', 'name']]
stopwords = {'is', 'a'}

expected output:
updated_list = [['this, 'test'],['what', 'your', 'name']]

current output:
updated_list = ['this, 'test','what', 'your', 'name']
```

Comment: Please add input and the corresponding expected output

Comment: okay, I added the input (articles) and the stopwords and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer list comprehensions, you can use this example:

```
articles = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'], ['what', 'is', 'your', 'name']]
stopwords = {'is', 'a'}


articles = [[word for word in article if word not in stopwords] for article in articles]
print(articles)
```

Prints:

```
[['this', 'test'], ['what', 'your', 'name']]
```

Comment: dang you make it look so easy and yet I cant believe I couldnt think of this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

So you want to append list to your list if I understand your question correctly.

This should do the work:

```
updated_list = []
articles = list_of_articles

for article in articles:
    temp_list = list()
    for word in article:
         if word not in stopwords:
             temp_list.append(word)
    updated_list.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the words of all articles into one list, you need to maintain separate lists for each article and finally add them to the `updated_list`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
updated_list = []
stopwords = {'is', 'a'}

articles = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'], ['what', 'is', 'your', 'name']]

for article in articles:
    lst = []
    for word in article:
        if word not in stopwords:
            lst.append(word)
    updated_list.append(lst)

print(updated_list)
```

**Output**

```
[['this', 'test'], ['what', 'your', 'name']]
```

But I suggest you use the following [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), as it is considered more *pythonic*:

```
stopwords = {'is', 'a'}
articles = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'], ['what', 'is', 'your', 'name']]

updated_list = [[word for word in article if word not in stopwords] for article in articles]
print(updated_list)
```

**Output**

```
[['this', 'test'], ['what', 'your', 'name']]
```

Comment: @JohnSpencer Glad I could help!